# How to get match links and use request on that links in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have some text (strings) that I scrapped.
now I want to get only matched link, and want to use get requests on those links.
here is sample codes.

[nordway, nord.download and ul is sample domain]

```
texts = """

https://ul.com/123

https://nord.download/view/11
https://nord.download/view/22

http://nordway.com/view/1
http://nordway.com/view/2
http://nordway.com/view/3
http://nordway.com/view/4
http://nordway.com/view/5

"""

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

match1= re.findall(r'(https://nord.download/?\S+)', texts)

match2 = re.findall(r'http://nordway.com/?\S+', texts)

print(match1)
print(match2)
```

Output:

```
print(match1)
['https://nord.download/view/11', 'https://nord.download/view/22']

print(match2)
['http://nordway.com/view/1', 'http://nordway.com/view/2', 'http://nordway.com/view/3', 'http://nordway.com/view/4', 'http://nordway.com/view/5']
```

**But I want to grab those links - as when nord.download link is found it will print or grab links, if not available (nord.download) output will found nordway.com, else result will be 'Not Found'**

But here I could not figure out how to put those two regex as exception or what i don't know.
or how to get both domain links if it is available.

and at the end, I want to use those links or a single link for requests data (using requests).

```
page = requests.get(match1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='lxml')
```

all links are used as examples. there is no valid link

if I make mistake, pardon me, and please help me get rid of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if match :
    responses={}
    counter=0
    for url in match :
        counter+=1
        responses["response"+str(counter)]=requests.get(url)
print(responses)
```

Comment: can you please explain me this?

Comment: using this method ,, of course changing match to match1 or match2 ,, what it will do is make get requests to each url inside match1 , match2 .. and it will save the results in a dictionary , with which you can access said results like this : for example let's say you want to get the content of the first url ,, responses['response1'].content

to use with beautiful soup

soup=BeautifulSoup(responses['response1'].content,'html.parser')


I don't know if I explained myself well... I don't speak English so this is translated by google :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `match1` directly with `requests.get()` because it is a sequence of urls, not just one url. Instead, you need a for loop to iterate over each url that you matched:

```
for url in match1:
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)
```

Comment: i got it but i also need it  - want to grab those links - as when nord.download link is found it will print or grab links, if not available (nord.download) output will found nordway.com, else result will be 'Not Found'

Comment: @Prottoy Ok, you will need to write the code to do that instead of just printing the response.

Comment: no about this, match1= re.findall(r'(https://nord.download/?\S+)', texts)

match2 = re.findall(r'http://nordway.com/?\S+', texts)

Comment: @Prottoy I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: match1= re.findall(r'(https://nord.download/?\S+)', texts)

match2 = re.findall(r'http://nordway.com/?\S+', texts)

here i got the result in two diff variables. also there the domain nordway.com or nord.download can be absent. 
i need logic there, if match1 is available it will print match1 and if match2 is available print match2, otherwise result n

Comment: @Prottoy Ok, that is much clearer and you describe what you want to do very well in English. What problem are you having translating that into python? Do you know how to do an `if` statement?

Comment: I am so sorry for making trouble. I know a little bit about if statement, but I tried but didn't get the results. can you please help to edit your comment and added if statement for the logic that I want?

Comment: @Prottoy Don't apologize. Everyone was once a beginner. At the same time, we expect you to make an attempt on your own. I suggest that you post a new question showing what you tried. Include the output you get and describe what you want instead.